# Every subgroup $H$ of a free abelian group $F$ is free abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups

I am working through a proof that every subgroup $H$ of a free abelian group $F$ is free abelian (for finite rank)

For the inductive step, let $\{ x_1, \ldots, x_n \}$ be a basis of $F$, let $F_n = \langle x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1} \rangle$, and let $H_n = H \cap F_n$. By induction $H_n$ is free abelian of rank $\le n-1$. Now $$H/H_n = H/(H \cap F_n) \simeq (H+F_n)/F_n \subset F/F_n \simeq \mathbb{Z}$$

The isomorphism I can't see is $$H/(H \cap F_n) \simeq (H+F_n)/F_n.$$ I guess there is a way to get this from the first isomorphism theorem, but I am having a hard time seeing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is the Third Isomorphism Theorem: given a group $G,$ a normal subgroup $K$ of $G$ and a subgroup $H$ of $G$ we have that
$$
HK/K \cong H/H\cap K.
$$
You rightly guessed that the proof uses the Fundamental Isomorphism Theorem. The homomorphism $f : HK \to H/H \cap K$ defined via
$$
f(hk) = h (H\cap K)
$$
where $h \in H$ and $k \in K$ is a surjective one and its kernel is $K.$

Comment: interesting. I do know this isomorphism theorem as well. I guess it was the product vs sum that was throwing me off

Answer (score 1):

Consider the composition
$$
H \stackrel{i}{\hookrightarrow} H + F_n \stackrel{\pi}{\to} (H + F_n)/F_n
$$
where $i$ is the inclusion and $\pi$ the projection. What's its kernel?

Comment: thanks the kernel is $H \cup F_n$. The result then follows

Comment: Sorry, that is $H \cap F_n$!